# Setting a JavaBeans collection-property in XML

Tags: java, xml, javabeans, logback

I'm creating a custom appender for LogBack. The appender needs a collection (or an array would work as well) of objects (Guice-modules to be precise). How should the corresponding xml-configuration look like?

In other words: I want to create a configuration file which enables LogBack to use the following methods when creating the appender:

```
            public List<Module> getModules() {
                            return modules;
            }

            public void setModules(List<Module> modules) {
                            this.modules = modules;
            }
```

A single instance is easy. Then the xml looks like this:

```
            <module class="guice.Base.ApplicationModule"></module>
```

How do I create the equivalent for multiple modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the "adder-pattern".

E.g.

XML:

```
<module class="guice.Base.ApplicationModule"></module>
<module class="guice.Base.PropertiesModule"></module>
```

Java:

```
public void addModule(Module module) {
       this.modules.add(module);
}
```